# How can I change a template via config.xml of custom module in Magento?

Tags: xml, magento, module

This content of my module's config.xml.

I want to change the onepage template file via this module.

It is works if I change code in onepage.xml, but I want to make this with my module.

Whats wrong in this code?

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_Mymodule>
            <version>1.0</version> 
        </Mynamespace_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <checkout_onepage_index>
                <reference name="checkout.onepage">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><template>mynamespace/mymodule/onepage.phtml</template></action>
                </reference>
            </checkout_onepage_index>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a layout from config.xml

You said that: I change code in onepage.xml -> looks like what you meant is checkout.xml
This is term of definition. We may have different definition of modules.

Let's say you have module in `app/code/local/[Mynamespace]/[Mymodule]`
Your `[Mymodule]` is calling `mymodule.xml`
Do you say it is called from your module?

1) If yes, then you can use this code in your `config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_Mymodule>
            <version>1.0</version> 
        </Mynamespace_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

That code will call layout named `mymodule.xml`
Then create the layout file in `app/design/frontend/[base/default]/[default/yourtheme]/layout/mymodule.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>mynamespace/mymodule/onepage.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

2) If no -> your definition of module is only files under `app/code/local/[Mynamespace]/[Mymodule]`, then you need to rewrite the Onepage's block

`config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_Mymodule>
            <version>1.0</version> 
        </Mynamespace_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Checkout_Onepage</onepage>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

With that config, your `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage` will be rewritten by `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Checkout_Onepage` (you can change the name as long as you keep the directory structure in a match).

For the example your file will be put in: `app/code/local/[Mynamespace]/[Mymodule]/Block/Checkout/Onepage.php`

Finally your `app/code/local/[Mynamespace]/[Mymodule]/Block/Checkout/Onepage.php` will be like this:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Checkout_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('mynamespace/mymodule/onepage.phtml');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. The first ideal what I needed. Have a nice day^^